# .htaccess to customize php url in folder

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, friendly-url

My php file is in this location:
https://example.com/store/store.php?id=1

and I want to rewrite it as:
https://example.com/store/store_name

I tried like below:

```
RewriteEngine On    # Turn on the rewriting engine
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule  ^([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/?$  store.php?id=$1 [NC,L] #Handle page requests
```

But it is not working for me.

Comment: `store_name` cannot just become `id=1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your shown samples, please try following htaccess Rules file. Make sure to place your htaccess Rules file in folder where store folder is present, place it along side with store folder NOT inside it.

Make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^store/(.*)/?$  store/store.php?id=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
```